# Why does this function return finaly?

Tags: dart

Why does this function return finaly? Is not we catching the error?

```
String _test(){
  try {
    throw Exception('error');
  } catch (e) {
    return 'catch';
  } finally {
    return 'finaly';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally block is executed regardless of catching the error. It always executes when the `try` block exits.

**EDIT:**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

> finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break.

From this quote, it is evident that `finally` is usually used for cleaning up the code. That's why it is executed before the `catch` block, to avoid being bypassed by `return`

Comment: This question was about Dart, not Java, so linking to and quoting Java documentation is not necessarily relevant.  Although Dart was influenced by Java, it is a separate language.  Also, it is incorrect to say that "[a `finally` block] is executed before the `catch` block".

Comment: try (re-)throwing in the catch block: That way, finally won't be called.